# JavaScript cannot retrieve value or length using IE Edge browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to get the value and length of an input within a form using JavaScript.  This works fine using Chrome and Firefox, but not with the Edge browser.  For this demo, I have made the code as simple as possible.  Edge returns value "undefined" and then evidently bombs out getting the length (does not alert or return false).  The console shows no errors.  Just shows HTML1300: Navigation occurred.

```js
function CheckFields() {
  alert('The value is |' + document.trantype.joinselect.value + '|');
  alert('The length is |' + document.trantype.joinselect.value.length + '|');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="trantype" style="display: inline;" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckFields()">
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_1">&nbsp;This is Radio 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_22">&nbsp;This is Radio 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_333">&nbsp;This is Radio 3<br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: try removing the return

Comment: @canon What's wrong with where the script is positioned?

Comment: @MoeenBasra Why would the return affect what the alert shows?

Comment: alert works perfectly with and with return,
but I was also having this type of issue in past that works without return.
If its still not working then let me know I will try to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the archaic method of accessing form elements as properties, use `document.querySelector()`.

```js
function CheckFields() {
  var button = document.querySelector("form[name=trantype] input[name=joinselect]:checked");
  if (button) {
    alert('The value is |' + button.value + '|');
    alert('The length is |' + button.value.length + '|');
  } else {
    alert('No button is selected');
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="trantype" style="display: inline;" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return CheckFields()">
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_1">&nbsp;This is Radio 1<br />
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_22">&nbsp;This is Radio 2<br />
  <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_333">&nbsp;This is Radio 3<br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I really appreciate your help.  That works.  I write a ton of PHP and keep up with the latest standards, but I write almost zero JavaScript.  I usually copy JavaScript from the Internet.  Looks like I have a lot of research to do as I have a lot of this old JavaScript code embedded in various web pages from 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try its working fine with older IEs also.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("form[name=trantype]")
 if(elem.addEventListener){
  elem.addEventListener("submit", callback, false);  //Modern browsers
 }else if(elem.attachEvent){
  elem.attachEvent('onsubmit', callback);            //Old IE
 }

    function callback(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('The value is |' + document.trantype.joinselect.value + '|');
  alert('The length is |' + document.trantype.joinselect.value.length + '|');
  return false;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test of Edge browser</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="trantype" style="display: inline;" action="#" method="post">
      <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_1">&nbsp;This is Radio 1<br />
      <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_22">&nbsp;This is Radio 2<br />
      <input type="radio" name="joinselect" value="Test_333">&nbsp;This is Radio 3<br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```